Add a value to a standard picklist field in salesforce
Using rest API, how to add new value to picklist for standard field without changing existing values.
How do I use the rest API to add a new picklist value to a standard field that already has many custom values.  Specifically, I do not want to overwrite the picklist because that would delete the custom values.  I just want to add a single new value to the list.
I investigated and found a way with the tools api {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N7R00000C83Hu but it only works for non-standard created fields.

Standard Picklists sit in different area of your sfdx project / Metadata API / Tooling API: StandardValueSet, full doc here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm
GET to /services/data/v61.0/tooling/sobjects/StandardValueSet/LeadSource threw  me a weird error ("INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION") so maybe Tooling API doesn't handle them well.
You may have to use the old school Metadata API, here's a snippet of apex: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8pe2SAB (calling metadata api from apex is not normally possible and no ETA, the trick is to use the wrapper created by Andy Fawcett: https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/). See what you can strip from it :)
